# Injecting static property values

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm having some trouble using my values from a `.properties` file.

My `my-properties.properties` file looks something like this:

```
email.host=smtp.googlemail.com
email.port=465
```

Then my Configuration file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my-properties.properties")
class MyProperties{

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

And then I'm trying to use it in this Email class:

```
@Component("MyProperties.class")
public class AutomatedEmail {

private String recipient;
private String fullName;
private String tempPassword;

private Email email;

@Value("email.from")
private String from;

...

public AutomatedEmail(){
}
public AutomatedEmail(final String recipient, final String fullName, final String tempPassword) throws EmailException {
    this.recipient = recipient;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.tempPassword = tempPassword;

}
```

But it is always coming back saying its null. I've also tried an Autowired approach and setting up the entire email object in the MyProperties class, but that is null also after I call my Constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the name in the properties file with curly brackets and a dollar sign to make a Spring expression.

```
@Value("${email.from}")
```

There's more info in [this tutorial on spring values](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/)

Edit: Note that this will only work if the bean has been instantiated and managed by the Spring container.  You won't be able to inject values into the bean if you just call `new Email();`.

Read through the spring doco on [bean IoC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) to get a better understanding.  And a bit more info on [how to instantiate beans.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-loosely-coupled-example/)

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that and now in `my-properties.properties` it shows the values as being used. But I'm still running into the problem with the values being null once I call the constructor. Do the values get assigned at compilation and then overwritten when I create that AutomatedEmail object I'm guessing?

Comment: Ah, i see what you're doing!  You need the bean to be managed through Spring.  You can't instantiate it using the `new` keyword.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you! Definitely have some more reading and refactoring to do!